Trouble with uv unwrapping looking like a cube when it's not a cube
I selected every edge and selected unwrap, but it just looks like a cube? I used a cube to build the model, but I edited it significantly enough I don't think it should look like a cube? I used a subdivision modifier and a mirror modifier, could that be affecting it?


try uv -> smart uv project instead of "just" unwrap
